# More WebSocket connections in a Wicket page

Tags: java, websocket, wicket

I'm trying to implement some **WebSocket** related code in our **Wicket** application. There is something I don't understand. How can I create more connections within a single page?

Looking in the documentation:

> When a client is connected it is being registered in a application scoped registry using as a key the application name, the client http session id, and the id of the page or the resource name that registered it. Later when the server needs to push a message it can use this registry to filter out which clients need to receive the message.

and

> By adding a (Base)WebSocketBehavior to your component(s) Wicket will contribute wicket-websocket-jquery.js library which provides some helper functions to write your client side code. There is a default websocket connection per Wicket Page opened for you which you can use like:
>
> `Wicket.WebSocket.send('{msg: "my message"}');`
>
> If you need more WebSocket connections then you can do:
>
> `var ws = new Wicket.WebSocket();`
> `ws.send('message');`

If I use the `new Wicket.WebSocket()` approach, how can I later get the registered connection from the connection registry? The `IWebSocketConnectionRegistry` allows to get the connection by a key composed from Application, sessionId and pageId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Default*WebSocketConnectionRegistry supports only one connection by key, but you can use your own impl of a registry to have a list per key.

Why do you need the second connection? Usually an application needs just one connection and uses the structure of the response message (e.g. JSON with some differentiator key) to decide how to process it in the browser.

Comment: I don't need it, I just don't understand how to get that connection in my server side.

Comment: You are right! I'll remove this from the documentation!

Comment: By the way, `SimpleWebSocketConnectionRegistry` just stores all connections. But it doesn't create keys for them. So if I use `var ws = new Wicket.WebSocket();` on client side, I would need to provide my own `IWebSocketProcessor`. Am I right?

Comment: Having a second websocket connection in the same page has never been fully explored. It seems it is not really supported at the server side. Unless someone finds a really good reason to support such use case I think it is better to just remove this from the documentation.